# Debug information for dynamically generated assembly

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

Is it possible to add debug information such as local variable names and source code information to dynamically generated assemblies using `AssemblyBuilder` / `TypeBuilder` / `MethodBuilder` in `System.Reflection.Emit`? I am specifically interested in whether this is possible in non-.NET Framework versions of .NET (e.g., .NET Core 5, 6, 7).

Answer (score 0):

There is [ISymbolDocumentWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.symbolstore.isymboldocumentwriter.aspx) (ModuleBuilder.DefineDocument), [ISymbolWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.symbolstore.isymbolwriter?view=net-7.0) (ModuleBuilder.GetSymWriter), [LocalBuilder.SetLocalSymInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.localbuilder.setlocalsyminfo?view=netframework-4.8.1) but they only implemented on Net Framework (see [issue1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7636#issuecomment-330715423), [issue2](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62956)). Anyway I'll recommend to use some wrapper around Reflection.Emit rather then using it directly, there are lots of them on NuGet/GitHub.

Alternatively:

1. You can use [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Debug-symbols) as IL writer (PDB writer is still Windows only, but at least you can target Core).
2. Roslyn API, but it's totally NOT lightweight.

Comment: Is there something implementing `ISymbolDocumentWriter` in .NET core though? For example, `SymDocumentWriter` that implements it, exists only in .NET Framework.

Comment: @PeroP No. See update.